# Negative output in Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting negative output when adding large numbers in Fibonacci sequence despite using *long int*. How to fix that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main() {

    long int sum = 2;
    long int f1 = 1, f2 = 2, f3;
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 4000000; i++) {
        f3 = f2 + f1;
        if (!(f3 % 2)) {
            sum += f3;
        }
        swap(f1, f2);
        swap(f2, f3);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

The output is -1833689714

Comment: Integer Overflow.

Comment: which is undefined behavior, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci-Folge#Definition_der_Fibonacci-Folge) the 47th Fibonacci Number exceeds the range of a 32Bit/4Byte integer. Everything after that will become negative.

For your program you used a long int which may or may not be 32 or 64 bits wide, the C++ standard does not guarantee that (for good reasons). If I see your result it seems like 32 Bit for me.

First, to prevent negativeness, you could use unsigned long int which makes all your results positive and gives the ability to model "slightly" bigger numbers.

However you will still get the wrong results if you pass the 47th Fibonacci number since your data type is still too small. To fix this you could use unsigned long long or uint64_t.

Remember even for such big datatypes that can represent numbers up to approx. 18 trillion/quintillion (10^18) the Fibonacci numbers exceed this at the 89th iteration.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter Number:";
    unsigned long long int x;
    cin>>x;
    unsigned long long int a=0,b=1,c;
    cout<<a<<"\t"<<b;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        c=a+b;
        cout<<"\t"<<c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
       return 0;
    }

}
```